# System keeps changing power mode while gaming

Tags: laptop, power-supply, charger

Recently my laptop keeps changing power mode while gaming, like if i disconnected the charger physically.

I don't have another charger to test, this is the stock one which has been running fine for 3 years until now.
Everything works without a problem if i'm not gaming, could this be a charger problem?

What can i do to verify what's the problem if not?

Answer (score 2):

This sometimes occurs when the graphic adapter is drawing too much current. Typically happens when you are gaming. Basically, what happens is that when you are heavily gaming, your graphic adapter becomes the main consumer of the power. When the current drawn from the charger is reaching the limit defined by the manufacturer, the overcurrent protection is triggered and all current is stopped. In this case, the laptop reacts as if the charger was disconnected and switches to the battery simultaneously reducing the CPU and GPU clock frequencies. After a while, it detects the charger and attempts to switch power source to it and the whole thing repeats again.

I have heard that several Asus laptops are suffering from this issue. It often happens that the laptop is compatible with more than one model of charger and the manufacturer supplies the one with the lowest power rating.

- One way to address the problem is to buy an adapter with higher power rating that is still compatible with your laptop (make sure to check compatibility).
- Another option is to play around with your graphic adapter settings and also change game settings to be less demanding.
- One more alternative method is to run the laptop without the battery. (Obviously, you will need to shut the laptop down before removing the battery). Sometimes this resolves the problem, though resulting into the lower performance in the games.

Comment: It's actually an ASUS, n56vz to be explicit (one of the first versions with win7), the problem i see with your answer is, this has been running this game for 2 years at this settings with no problems, yes, it's at maximum settings. 

Could this be a nvidia driver problem? Cause i've tried to reduce quality in the game and it still does this.

Edit: the charger (stock) has output: +19V, 6.32A.

Comment: If you haven't changed anything in your software and game setup recently, it could be the charging circuit problem. The degradation of components over time etc. Asus are famous for the issues with their charges not supplying enough current to their powerful hardware.

Comment: If you have a possibility to borrow the compatible charger with 19V and higher Amps value - try it and see if this resolves the problem. Meanwhile you can try the "no-battery" method described above. Few of my friedns (Asus owners) alway disconnect the battery when they are gaming. I don't think it is a perfect solution, but if it stops the screen from flickering... you know

Comment: I haven't, the only thing changed was the nvidia drivers updates, latest one last week, although i can't remember if this started happening after a specific update, but it's been on for sometime before this last one too...

Comment: It very well could be the driver update. As I have said the GPU is usually draining a lot of power. The change in the mode of the GPU cause by the new driver could have resulted in higher power consumption. If your laptop was working on the limit of the PSU's capability, then this small change could have pushed it beyound the red line

Comment: ok, thanks for your help, i'll try the no-battery solution later today, i'm doing some updates right now, i'll keep updating this.

Comment: Be careful with the no-battery solution though. It mostly works for Asus owners, but back up your data just in case (not that I am trying to scare you, but being careful does not hurt)

Comment: Backup my data in what sense? In the sense of the pc shuting down as it not having a battery mode to switch to? I don't want to fry my board if that's the other sense lol.

Comment: In a sense that you always backup your data before experimenting with hardware setup

Comment: Just want to report here that this issue somehow fixed itself, no software or driver change, so... idk.